# GPO install application and then service pack

Tags: group-policy, deployment

**scenario**:
I have a GPO for deploying *SoftwareABC.msi* and every computer that fits GPO will have SoftwareABC installed.
Now I have a Service Pack *SoftwareABC_SP1.msi*, deployed new GPO and it deployed also.

**problem**:
When a new PC is configured, it sometimes conflicts with trying to install ServicePack before the owner application.

**solution**:
Any ideas on avoiding such behavior?

Comment: GPO is not the right tool to use to deploy software nowadays, use something such as Configuration Manager or Intune for example.

Comment: I can't go with SCCM licensing..
As a fast solution, I am introducing GPO based.

Right now, I am researching and comparing PDQ vs OPSI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deploying the software package you could create a PowerShell script which does the deployment and will be triggered by a GPO, which checks if there are ongoing installations are, and if the service pack is already installed.

```
# Main application MSI file
$mainApplicationMSI = "SoftwareABC.msi"

# Service pack MSI file
$servicePackMSI = "SoftwareABC_SP1.msi"

# Check if the main application is installed
function IsMainApplicationInstalled {
    $mainAppInstalled = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $mainApplicationMSI }
    return [bool]$mainAppInstalled
}

# Check if the main application is installed
if (IsMainApplicationInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Main application is already installed. Proceeding with service pack installation."
    
    # Install the service pack
    Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i `"$servicePackMSI`" /qn" -Wait
} else {
    Write-Host "Main application is not installed. Please install the main application first."
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.
It seems a logical approach, I will give it a try.